# react-router history cannot read property location of undefined

Tags: react-router

I am using `react-router: "^3.0.2",`  and `history": "^3.0.0` and I have setup my `redux` store like:

```
import { createHistory } from 'history';

export default function configureStore() {


    let createStoreWithMiddleware = composeEnhancers(
        applyMiddleware(thunk),
        reduxReactRouter({ routes, createHistory })
        )(createStore)

    const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(rootReducer)

    return store
}
```

It gives me error like `cannot read property location of undefined` .

How can I solve this ?